# Ember-data multi-word model fields not serialized properly

Tags: serialization, ember.js, ember-data

I'm seeing some odd behavior with some custom serializer code that I wrote.

I have a field in an Asset model called 'marketName'.  My Rails backend expects this field to be called 'market_name'.  I've extended the ActiveModelSerializer and have overridden the 'extractSingle' and 'serialize' methods.

The odd thing is this - for all the other fields in my Asset model that are not made up of multiple words - the serialization code that I've written works great. No issues.  However - for any field containing multiple words - the serialization doesn't work completely, in that while it saves the Asset when created - it doesn't correctly populate the Asset model's 'marketName' field (and any other field that is made up of multiple words).

For example if I examine the 'marketName' field in the data inspector it appears as '{}'. If I change the name of any multi word field in my Asset model to be singular (aka change 'marketName' to 'name') and update the serialization code accordingly - everthing works great.

Any idea what's going on ?

Thanks
Dave

Comment: Sharing your serializer and some of the other relevant code would be a big help

Comment: You should handle multi word property names in your `serialize` and `extractSingle` methods. Generally speaking, you shouldn't override these methods.

Answer (score 0):

In the test of `extractSingle()` that the core team (see [line 126](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/65051a7ae6d4256536a60fba6e7df3190b71a989/packages/activemodel-adapter/tests/integration/active_model_serializer_test.js), also show below incase link goes bad for future readers) did, they pass in the variables as `super_villains`, then later the `normalize()` included in `ActiveModelSerializer` changes it for them to `superVillains`.

So I think in your [extractSingle](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html#method_extractSingle) assume the values are not yet camelCase, but still are still in underscore_format (e.g., "market_name"), and you should be golden!

```
test("extractSingle", function() {
  env.container.register('adapter:superVillain', DS.ActiveModelAdapter);

  var json_hash = {
    home_planet:   {id: "1", name: "Umber", super_villain_ids: [1]},
    super_villains:  [{
      id: "1",
      first_name: "Tom",
      last_name: "Dale",
      home_planet_id: "1"
    }]
  };

  var json = env.amsSerializer.extractSingle(env.store, HomePlanet, json_hash);

  deepEqual(json, {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Umber",
    "superVillains": [1]
  });

  env.store.find("superVillain", 1).then(async(function(minion){
    equal(minion.get('firstName'), "Tom");
  }));
});
```